# What is the correct way to recognize BE errors from network error in angular http POST?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I checked https://angular.io/guide/http and it tells that they can be distinguished by test

```js
if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
  console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
}
```

However setting the laptop in Airplane mode does not result this condition to be true when request fails. I've also seen examples of changing the calling code and checking for statuscode === 0. This also seems to never happen.